# "detail": "method \delete\ not allowed" django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I made a view that can use put, delete request using modelviewset and mapped it with url. I have clearly made it possible to request put and delete request to url, but if you send delete request to url, I return 405 error. What's wrong with my code? Here's my code.

views.py

```
class UpdateDeletePostView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwner]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    def update (self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({'success': '게시물이 수정 되었습니다.'}, status=200)

    def destroy (self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({'success': '게시물이 삭제 되었습니다.'}, status=200)
```

feed\urls.py

```
path('post/<int:pk>', UpdateDeletePostView.as_view({'put': 'update', 'delete': 'destroy'})),
```

server\urls.py

```
path('feed/', include('feed.urls')),
```

and error

```
"detail": "method \delete\ not allowed"
```

Comment: Hi, I have a question: "Why do you use a `ViewSet` to handle just operations of a single record" ?

Comment: Does `update` work?

Comment: What's your entire url? How do you reach `DELETE /feed/post/<int:pk>/` ?

Comment: @HuLuViCa no update is not worked too :(

Comment: @TomWojcik my entire url is <DELETE /feed/post/<int:pk>

Comment: I can see you are missing a trailing slash on your path. Try with it `path('post/<int:pk>/', UpdateDeletePostView.as_view({'put': 'update', 'delete': 'destroy'}))`

Comment: I always didn't put a slash on the end, but it never didn't work. All other urls in the other side did not have slashes attached to the end, but they worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I wrote in the comment looks like you don't need a `ViewSet` because you are handling just operations on a single item.
In general you can restrict the operations available for Views or ViewSet using proper mixins.

I suggest two possible approaches

**Use Generic View**

```py
class UpdateDeletePostView(
        UpdateModelMixin,
        DeleteModelMixin,
        GenericAPIView):
    .....
```

and

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>', UpdateDeletePostView.as_view()),
    ...
]
```

**Use ViewSet and Router**

```py
class UpdateDeletePostViewSet(
        UpdateModelMixin,
        DeleteModelMixin,
        GenericViewset):
    .....
```

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('feed', UpdateDeletePostViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you for advising about my code :) But first I wonder why my code doesn't work.

Comment: to be honest I never used a ViewSet without a Router; so my guess was that the "manual" way of configuring the ViewSet was the root cause of the problem.
Maybe you could try to write a Unit Test and debug the code

Comment: Unfortunately, other viewsets that manually mapped url all worked normally :(

Comment: can you write a UT and see the whole stacktrace ??

Answer (score 2):

TLDR;

Use the detail-item endpoint instead of the list-items endpoint.

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/items/<item-id>/`

instead of

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/items/`

---

This happened with a project I was working on. Turns out I was trying to PUT, PATCH, DELETE from the list-items endpoint rather than the detail-item endpoint.

If you implemented your viewset using the ModelViewSet class, and your GET and POST methods work. Chances are you may be using the wrong endpoint.

Example:
If you're trying to retrieve all your products from you use the list-items endpoint which will look something like:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/`

If you're trying to get the detail of a specific item, you use the detail-item endpoint which looks like:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/2/`

Where `2` is the id of the specific product that you're trying to `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE`. The reason you get the 405 is because it is your fault (not the servers fault), that you're applying item-level methods to an endpoint that provides lists of items - making your request ambiguous.