# Python/Docker - Method delete not allowed Django

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to run a program using docker that will allow me to destroy requests by using a program called PostMan to do this I have set up a class named ProductViewSet which will allow me to delete a query. But when I run docker-compose up in my Visual Studio Terminal and try to run a DELETE query through PostMan it gives me an error in PostMan that says "detail": method "DELETE" not allowed. I have tried to use the @action function to try and link the destroy function from my views.py to my urls.py in the same folder using this answer [Method Delete Not Allowed - destroy() method Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379472/method-delete-not-allowed-destroy-method-django), I have also tried to just use my main function Product and use a router as seen in this answer ["detail": "method \delete\ not allowed" django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64715929/detail-method-delete-not-allowed-django) but both of these answers do not help me at all.

Here is my error that I am getting in PostMan and in my Visual Studio Terminal:

Postman:

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"DELETE\" not allowed."
}
```

Visual Studio Terminal:

```
backend_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2022 00:58:14] "DELETE /api/products HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Here are my requirements.txt, Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, views.py, and urls.py files respectivly:

requirements.txt:

```
Django==3.1.3
djangorestframework==3.12.2
mysqlclient==2.0.1
django-mysql==3.9
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
pika==1.1.0
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    ports:
      - 8020:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  queue:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python -u consumer.py'
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: veganettest
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33070:3306
```

views.py file:

```
#**************************************************
#  VEGA Copyright (C) Tetra System Solutions 2022                                               
#                                                 
#  Author: Trevor R. Blanchard                                               
#                                                  
#**************************************************

# imports that will allow us to use the django rest framework with our project 
# and will allow us to use our Product, and User classes to create our viewset.

from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from .models import Product, User
from .producer import publish
from .serializers import ProductSerializer
import random

# Here is where our view set is defined.

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    # lists all queries available on PostMan
    def list(self, request):
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    # creates a query that we can interact with 
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        publish('product_created', serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    # retreives a query from our list
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    # updates the list of queries
    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(instance=product, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        publish('product_updated', serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
    # deletes a query
    def destroy(self, request, pk=None): # this function is involved with the Method delete not allowed error.
        product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
        product.delete()
        publish('product_created', pk)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

# creates a view for the user so he/she can view the product. 
class UserAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, _):
        users = User.objects.all()
        user = random.choice(users)
        return Response({
            'id': user.id
        })
```

urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import ProductViewSet, UserAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    path('profiles', ProductViewSet.as_view({
        'get': 'list',
        'post': 'create'
    })),
    path('profiles/<str:pk>', ProductViewSet.as_view({
        'get': 'retrieve',
        'put': 'update',
        'delete': 'destroy'
    })),
    path('user', UserAPIView.as_view())
]
```

What exactly can I do to fix this code? thank you!

Comment: Can you show your rest framework settings and urls.py files?

Comment: Perhaps its because your view class only has a `get()` method. There is no `delete()` method defined.

Comment: Yes @sytech I will edit the question to include the urls.py, thank you.

Comment: Your request does not contain a primary key: `DELETE /api/products`. Since ProductViewSet is listed twice in your URLconf, it is going to match against the first entry. That first entry does not contain a delete action. I believe that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: Thank you @NickODell I will try to add a delete request in the first entry.

Comment: @NickODell Your solution had solved the question, thank you!

Comment: @KronosHedronos2077 You're welcome. I turned the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this request:

```
backend_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2022 00:58:14] "DELETE /api/products HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Your request does not contain a primary key. That means it's going to match this entry in your URLconf:

```
    path('profiles', ProductViewSet.as_view({
        'get': 'list',
        'post': 'create'
    })),
```

This does not contain an action for DELETE. You do have an action defined for delete here:

```
    path('profiles/<str:pk>', ProductViewSet.as_view({
        'get': 'retrieve',
        'put': 'update',
        'delete': 'destroy'
    })),
```

But this URL requires a primary key. You need to either change the URL that you're sending a DELETE request to, or add a delete method to the first entry in your URLconf.